# How to put two View tags in one parent View tag in React native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React native project, In my project I am trying to put different text in One 
View component and other text in Another View component.
But If I do like that then I am unable to see  first View component content on my screen.
So someone help me.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
        <Text>About us</Text>
        <Text>Services</Text>
        <Text>Contact</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={([styles.container], {backgroundColor: 'red'})}>
        <Text>Products</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#ff0000',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you are giving the same style(**flex:1 take the whole page**) to the second `View` tag, just change your code to ===>

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
        <Text>About us</Text>
        <Text>Services</Text>
        <Text>Contact</Text>

        </View>
        <View style={{alignItems:"center"}}>
        <Text>Products</Text>
        </View>
     </View>
  );
};


export default App;
```

as result you will be have :[image]

Comment: Hi @Amir Doreh I tried your code but why padding is not correctly applied to container and container2

Comment: If I put don't put  flex and flexDirection, justifyContent  then it is working. In that case container styles are only applying to Home, About us, Services, Contact. But not to View component.

Comment: you shoud give it to main parent

Comment: i misstyped it , now check the code, if you give a flex:1 to any children without giving to others it will take the whole page

Comment: Hi @AmirDoreh Exactly what I am expecting is   the output should be   like this Home  About us   Services  Contact wants to be in side by side under that products should come

Comment: if it helped you, please upvote and mark as answer so when any one have the same problem they can figure the answer , thanks, happy coding <3 @Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `flex: 1` to your container view

```
return (
   <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <View style={[styles.container]}>
       <Text>Home</Text>
       <Text>About us</Text>
       <Text>Services</Text>
       <Text>Contact</Text>
     </View>
     <View style={([styles.container], {backgroundColor: 'red'})}>
        <Text>Products</Text>
     </View>
   </View>
 );
```

and maybe there're a problem with second view style, i think it should be:

```
style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this , here we only gave flex to main container which will take all the space on page , then we place two components on it.

```
  import React from 'react';
    import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

    const App = props => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <Text>About us</Text>
            <Text>Services</Text>
            <Text>Contact</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.container1}>
            <Text>Products</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      maincontainer: {
        marginTop: 10,
        padding: 10,
       backgroundColor: '#fff',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
      },
        container: {
        marginTop: 10,
        height:100,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#bbb',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      },
        container1: {
        marginTop: 10,
        height:100,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#424242',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      },
    });


 export default App;
```

Hope it helps , feel free for doubts.